# Install Ros Indigo without downloading it everytime via terminal

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simply said, I have to install ROS Indigo on different computers, multiple times. 
My plan was to install ROS on a computer, once, following this tutorial ["http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu"](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)
and then transfer(?) the files to another computer and compile them.
Reason for doing this is I don't have unlimited internet nor great download speeds and neither a stable connection.
So, is there a way to transfer Ros from one computer to another, offline?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316708/install-ros-indigo-without-downloading-it-everytime-via-terminal/) by [Battu007](https://answers.ros.org/users/40218/battu007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:\

> [..] then transfer(?) the files to another computer and compile them.

"compile them"? The installation guide you link to installs binaries from `.deb`s. Nothing gets compiled.

Can you clarify?

**Comment by [Battu007](https://answers.ros.org/users/40218/battu007/) on 2019-02-26**:
Fairly new here so I don't know how binaries work. "Compile them", basically meant install them. Through binaries, could I perform an offline installation after downloading them?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2019-02-26**:
@Battu007 why don't you just automate the whole process by writing simple bash script?

**Comment by [Battu007](https://answers.ros.org/users/40218/battu007/) on 2019-02-26**:
A bash script will just automate the process of "downloading" ros each time, which is something I don't want to do. What i'm looking for is to transfer ros from one computer to another, offline (if that is possible).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
See also #q296864 btw, of which your question is essentially a duplicate.

**Comment by [Battu007](https://answers.ros.org/users/40218/battu007/) on 2019-02-26**:
Right, that should work for me. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Through binaries, could I perform an offline installation after downloading them?

this is indeed what you'd want to do.

Copying individual files / directories is not going to be either scalable or maintainable.

The keywords here are: "download deb packages for off-line computer" or similar.

Example results: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974).

This is not ROS specific, but an approach that works for *any* `.deb` based software distribution (please also note that I'm not endorsing or recommending any of the tools that are mentioned in the linked AskUbuntu Q&A).

An alternative could be to create an actual `apt` mirror on one of your machines that does have internet. If you have a network setup between your PCs, you could use the local mirror as an `apt` source which would allow your other computers to install the same packages without downloading them from `packages.ros.org` again.

---

Edit: a proper solution would apparently be to use [`apt-offline`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835655) for this. I've never used that myself though, so I can't comment on its usability.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I use ansible scripts (playbooks) to install and maintain all my ros installations.

## MasterPC:

apt-cacher-ng as caching proxy to avoid unneccessary internet traffic.

ansible + simple playbook for ros installation and updates

## ROS systems:

basic small ubuntu system

sshd enabled

python-minimal

catkin_ws via git (save and restore own projects)

Works painless for years now.

---

Originally posted by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) with karma: 476 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Battu007](https://answers.ros.org/users/40218/battu007/) on 2019-02-26**:
Oh, I'll check those out too, Thanks for helping out :)

**Comment by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on 2019-02-27**:
if you need some more support, drop me note :-)